# c++ Find all values of all objects in a class

Tags: c++, class, oop, object

I'm making a simple 2d platformer and I need to find all the values of all objects created, these objects would represent the in game collidables. So I would need all of the x/y co-ordinates, width and height so that I can check if any of them are colliding with the player.

Class Looks like:

```
class CollidableObject
{
  public:

    CollidableObject();
    virtual ~CollidableObject();

    int Height;
    int Width;
    DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector2 position;
    bool collidable;
};
```

It's obviously a very simple class and I just need a way to find out if the player position collides with any of the collidable objects values, I don't need collision code just a way to get at all of the collidable objects values at once. Hope I've made it clear.

Comment: Make a `vector` or `list` holding those Objects. Iterate through it and for every element check if it collides with a player.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CollisionPred(
public:
    CollisionPred( Player p) : p_(p) {}
    bool operator()(const ColiidableObject& o) {
         // process object and return true if there is a collision, i.e:
         return o.Height*o.Height + o.Width*o.Width > p_.distance;
    }
    private:
         Player p_;
;

int main() {
    //...
    std::vector<CollidableObject> v(100);
    std::vector<CollidableObject>::iterator it = 
                             std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), CollisionPred());
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and yet, the most popular way of doing it is to just iterate through a collection of collidables to check if any collides with a player.

```
vector<CollidableObject> objects;

for(CollidableObject& obj: objects)
{
    if (obj.position.x - obj.width < player.position.x + player.radius
     && obj.position.x + obj.width > player.position.x - player.radius
     && obj.position.y - obj.height < player.position.y + player.radius
     && obj.position.y + obj.height > player.position.y - player.radius
    )
    // collision happened

}
```

Comment: change auto obj: CollidableObject   for auto obj: objects, also you don't get this way an partiular object, find_if returns an iterator to an object

Comment: Thanks :) but I'm not seeing any objects in the vector upon debugging, I'm just creating new objects like this: CollidableObject CollidableBox

Comment: So there is only one instance of a collidable object in your game?

Comment: @tomi.lee.jones there could be as many as I want but at the moment I'm just testing with two, If I understand you correctly. Sorry I'm pretty new to oop

Comment: I understand, but i am sure in a very short time you will end up with more than just two and then you will need to put them in some container. But regardless of how many there is, the logic stays the same: if there is one object, just remove the loop. The `if` statement remains. Why does it not answer your case? What you really want to do? Do you want to get the values from all objects _at the same time_?